# How to trigger Angular FormControl validation without triggering valueChanges?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I'm curious if anyone has found a way to trigger validation without using
`updateValueAndValidity()` (which also triggers `valueChanges` on a FormControl according to [the docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updatevalueandvalidity) which isn't always a desired behavior) or `markAsTouched()` (which is simply incorrect as we didn't *touch* the control).

A workaround that comes to mind would be to extract validators logic in a way that it could be executed  outside of FormControl and then do `setErrors()` based on the results, but maybe there's a better way of doing that?

Comment: XY, why? What do you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See official doc:

https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updateValueAndValidity

> emitEvent: When true or not supplied (the default), both the statusChanges and valueChanges observables emit events with the latest status and value when the control is updated. When false, no events are emitted.

Edit:
So you can validate without emitting an event.

Comment: he wants to update the status and not the validity. He even expressedly said not to use updateValueAndValidity ...

Comment: with `updateValueAndValidity({emitEvent:false})` not execute change, see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fkuo7v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) I like this answer

Comment: I'd just like to suplement the answer - as @MGX recognized the problem (and I failed to properly explain in the question) was to trigger `statusChange` without `valueChange`. I took a closer look at the source code of [abstract_model.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/c14c701775c900ce9ac8781c08fc76da067910c5/packages/forms/src/model/abstract_model.ts) and as `updateValueAndValidity({emitEvent:false})` will not emit any of the events, I found in order to trigger `statusChange` the method we just need to use `setErrors()` afterwards, it is the only way to do that

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem to this and found @Kamil-now's comment on the accepted answer most helpful, suggesting:

```
control.setErrors(control.errors);
```